# Using Hibernate DetachedCriteria for calling aggregate functions

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have a `DetachedCriteria` which I am using to search a table based on a name field. I want to make the search case-insensitive, and am wondering if there is a way to do this without using HQL. Something like:

```
private void searchByFullName(DetachedCriteria criteria, String searchCriteria) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("fullName", "%" + searchCriteria.toLowerCase() + "%"));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("fullName"));
}
```

But I want to make sure that it will ignore the case when it does the search (it has to search for both the upper and lower case), so the SQL it generates should look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ? LIKE toLower(FULL_NAME);
```

Comment: if you have lots of row in that table, the engine will have to do a table scan do the `toLower(FULL_NAME)`, which you might not want to. One alternative is to store it as all lowercase or to add another column that is used only for search in which you store it all in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? MySQL LIKE is case-insensitive for CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT columns (I believe the same is true for SQL Server).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html

If you're using PostgreSQL, you'll want to use the ILIKE operator, so you'll want to use Restrictions.ilike("fullName", name).

Answer (score 0):

I see two options,

**Option 1:**

```
private void searchByFullName(DetachedCriteria criteria, String searchCriteria) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("toLower(fullName)", "%" + searchCriteria.toLowerCase() + "%"));
            criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("fullName"));
    }
```

**Option 2:**

```
private void searchByFullName(DetachedCriteria criteria, String searchCriteria) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("toLower({alias}.fullName) LIKE '%" + searchCriteria.toLowerCase() + "%'"));
                criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("fullName"));
        }
```

I am not very optimistic about Option 1. Option 2 should work for sure. `{alias}` is placeholder to let Hibernate know that it needs to add the appropriate alias for the table when it creates the SQL. More info http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29